# How to Run PostgreSQL by using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

Goal:
Run Postgres in docker by pulling postgres from docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

Background:
I get a message when I tried running docker with postgres

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
```

I got info at https://andrew.hawker.io/dailies/2020/02/25/postgres-uninitialized-error/ about why.

Problem:
"Update your docker-compose.yml or corresponding configuration with the POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD environment variable to revert back to previous behavior or implement a proper password." (https://andrew.hawker.io/dailies/2020/02/25/postgres-uninitialized-error/)

I don't understand the solution about how to solve the current situation.
Where can i find the dokcer-compose.yml?

Info:
*I'm newbie in PostGre and Docker

Comment: "Can you please share your folder tree so we can see more of your project organization? Thanks" - @ABCDEFGH

Comment: Do you have a sample to show about what folder tree you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run PostgreSQL in docker you will have to use a variable in docker run command like this :

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

The error is telling you the same.
Read more at https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose.yml is just another option. You can run it just by docker run like in first answer. If you want use docker-compose, in documentation is example of it:

#### stack.yaml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

and run: `docker-compose -f stack.yml up`.
Everything is here:
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres